# Tkinter smtplib error not defined

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error, smtplib

I am trying to make a program that is sending an email. But if I try it I get the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pivo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Pivo\Desktop\emailtkinter.py", line 24, in th
    server.sendmail(vari2.get(), toaddrs12, message)
NameError: name 'server' is not defined
```

**Complete Code:**

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
class FullScreenApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)            
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom

app=FullScreenApp(root)
def fn():
    def th():
        a = text.get("1.0", END)
        dgc = assa.get()
        message = dgc, a
        server.sendmail(vari2.get(), toaddrs12, message)
        server.quit
    Label(root, text='To').pack()
    toaddrs12 = StringVar()
    toaddrs1 = Entry(root, textvariable=toaddrs12).pack()
    Label(root, text='Subject').pack()
    assa = StringVar()
    ass = Entry(root, textvariable=assa).pack()
    Label(root, text='Body').pack()
    text = Text(root)
    text.pack()
    btn = Button(root, text='Send', command=th)
    btn.pack()

b = Label(root, text='SMTP Server')
vari1 = StringVar()
ab = Entry(root, textvariable=vari1)
b.pack()
ab.pack()
ba = Label(root, text = 'Email')
ba.pack()
vari2 = StringVar()
c = Entry(root, textvariable=vari2)
c.pack()
ca = Label(root, text = 'Password')
ca.pack()
vari3 = StringVar()
widget = Entry(root, show="*", textvariable=vari3)
widget.pack()

def connect():
    print(vari1.get())
    print(vari2.get())
    print(vari3.get())
    server = smtplib.SMTP(vari1.get(), 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(vari2.get(), vari3.get())
    b.pack_forget()
    ab.pack_forget()
    ba.pack_forget()
    c.pack_forget()
    ca.pack_forget()
    widget.pack_forget()
    btn1.pack_forget()
    fn()
btn1 = Button(root, command = connect, text = 'Connect')
btn1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare the variable server as global

```
global server
server = smtplib.SMTP(vari1.get(), 587)
```

In addition you must correct the function, you must concatenate the data. 
If you do `a, b` you are creating a tuple: `(a, b)` and not the required string

```
def th():
    contents = text.get("1.0", END)
    subject = assa.get()
    message = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, contents)
    server.sendmail(vari2.get(), toaddrs12.get(), message)
    server.quit()
```

**Complete Code:**

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


class FullScreenApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        pad = 3
        self._geom = '200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth() - pad, master.winfo_screenheight() - pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>', self.toggle_geom)

    def toggle_geom(self, event):
        geom = self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom, self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom = geom


app = FullScreenApp(root)


def fn():
    def th():
        contents = text.get("1.0", END)
        subject = assa.get()
        message = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, contents)
        server.sendmail(vari2.get(), toaddrs12.get(), message)
        server.quit()

    Label(root, text='To').pack()
    toaddrs12 = StringVar()
    toaddrs1 = Entry(root, textvariable=toaddrs12).pack()
    Label(root, text='Subject').pack()
    assa = StringVar()
    ass = Entry(root, textvariable=assa).pack()
    Label(root, text='Body').pack()
    text = Text(root)
    text.pack()
    btn = Button(root, text='Send', command=th)
    btn.pack()


b = Label(root, text='SMTP Server')
vari1 = StringVar()
ab = Entry(root, textvariable=vari1)
b.pack()
ab.pack()
ba = Label(root, text='Email')
ba.pack()
vari2 = StringVar()
c = Entry(root, textvariable=vari2)
c.pack()
ca = Label(root, text='Password')
ca.pack()
vari3 = StringVar()
widget = Entry(root, show="*", textvariable=vari3)
widget.pack()


def connect():
    print(vari1.get())
    print(vari2.get())
    print(vari3.get())
    global server
    server = smtplib.SMTP(vari1.get(), 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(vari2.get(), vari3.get())
    b.pack_forget()
    ab.pack_forget()
    ba.pack_forget()
    c.pack_forget()
    ca.pack_forget()
    widget.pack_forget()
    btn1.pack_forget()
    fn()


btn1 = Button(root, command=connect, text='Connect')
btn1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```